# Set and drag a Marker on Leaflet-map updates form input-field without sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

including leaflet and jQuery in the head, I have this code:

```
<form name="formone"> ...
<div id="clickmap">
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = L.map('map').setView([34.00, 8.00, 6);   
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(map);
function onMapClick(e)  {
    var lat = (e.latlng.lat);
    var lng = (e.latlng.lng);
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {draggable:true}).addTo(map).bindPopup($('<a href="#clickmap">Remove ME</a>').click(function() { map.removeLayer(marker);     })[0]);

// latnew = marker._latlng.lat;  // test        
// latold = document.formone.GPSLatitude.value; // test
                        }
map.on('click', onMapClick);

// function simply() {} // test
</script>

</div><!-- end clickmap -->

...

<input type="text" name="GPSLatitude" onclick="javascript:simply();" value="<?php echo $GPSLatitudeDec; ?>" size="25" maxlength="20" />
...

... </form>
```

With a click, I set a marker on the map.
In this procedure I would like to update the input-field,
before submitting. Also, if I drag the marker on the map,
the input-field should become updated.

And the last marker can become deleted too,
so that I've to deal only with one marker.

Can someone give me an overview, how to do that?

I'm not to exercised in the jQuery- or Leaflet-libaries. 
Are there any functions workarounds prepared?

Thank you,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you have two textboxes on your page, how about updating their values from inside the onMapClick(e) function?

```
...
<p>Latitude: <input id="latInput"> :: Longitude: <input id="lngInput"></p>
<script>
...
function onMapClick(e)  {

... //whatever code you've already put

document.getElementById('latInput').value = lat;
document.getElementById('lngInput').value = lng;
}
...
</script>
```

Edit: Similar answer shared here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272673/4355695, with working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/iyMhaoAyllr2uNSOHhS9?p=preview

Edit: worked out a full solution with both drag and click, and having reverse functionality too (user-entered values in form fields can move the marker). It also remembers the previous location marked by the user. See
working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PTFlun?p=preview