# Leaflet - draggable marker and coordinates display in a field form

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have to do a draggable marker and its coordinates should be displayed in fields. It will be a part of a contact form in PHP. I created a draggable marker, help me what to do now.

```
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(53.471, 18.744), {
draggable: true
}).addTo(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xTh5U/

Here is example in Google Maps API, I need the same in Leaflet.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use the dragend event of L.Marker, so you known dragging has ended, then get the coordinates of the marker by using the getLatLng method of L.Marker. When you've fetched those you can assign them to the values of your text inputs.

```
marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iyMhaoAyllr2uNSOHhS9?p=preview

Comment: How to make this in python? I'm using folium

Answer (score 8):

Came across this while looking for a similar solution. Forked the marked answer and took it a little further:

- Both drag and click; and map centers on the marker.
- Works in reverse as well (user-entered values in form fields can move
  the marker).
- Remembers the previous location marked by the user.

operative code:

```
marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
    updateLatLng(marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
    });
map.on('click', function (e) {
marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
updateLatLng(marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
});

function updateLatLng(lat,lng,reverse) {
if(reverse) {
marker.setLatLng([lat,lng]);
map.panTo([lat,lng]);
} else {
document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
map.panTo([lat,lng]);
}
}
```

See working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PTFlun?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, this is ideal for my use!